# How to build the half-left corner pyramid in c

Tags: c, string, loops, cs50

I want to build left-half-pyramid

```
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
  #######
 ########
#########
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter the height of the pyramid:");
    unsigned int height = GetInt();
    int counter;

    while(height <1 || height >23){
        printf("Incorect number,try again:");
        height = GetInt();
    }

    for(counter = 2;counter <=height+1;++counter) {
        printf("%.*s\n", counter, "##############################");
    }



}
```

I built the pyramid but instead of left corner i got right corner pyramid.
How can i turn it to the left side?

P.S I know, that usage of printf in this case is not the best idea, but it was told to me to create the code with this command.

Comment: `printf("%*.*s\n", height+1, counter,...`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you, it works. But, can you please explain what does this coude do. I mean each input(especially the first one).

Comment: see [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Now i got it. Thanks

Comment: @BLUEPIXY consider making an answer for OP to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k;
    printf("How many lines long ?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<n-i; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(k = 0; k<i; k++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
How many lines long ?
10

         #
        ##
       ###
      ####
     #####
    ######
   #######
  ########
 #########
##########


#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k;
    printf("How many lines long ?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    n++;
    for(i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<n-i; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(k = 0; k<i; k++)
        {
            if(i == 1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

Output:
How many lines long ?
10


         ##
        ###
       ####
      #####
     ######
    #######
   ########
  #########
 ##########
###########
```